# How to describe the selling price calculation

Tags: terminology, percentages

To determine the selling price of an item after marking it up by say 20% on SALES value, I use the formula cost price/0.8. The 0.8 comes from the difference between 100% and 20% ie 0.8. Is there a mathematical term for that difference?

Comment: Not clear... You ave the VALUE of the product= $100$. You have the MARK UP = $20$. Thus the SELLING PRICE will be = $100+20=120$. If so, COST/PRICE= $100/120= 83,3%$.

Comment: Because PRICE=COST + MARK UP, we have two possibilities: either MARK UP/COST = $20/100= 20%$ or MARK UP/PRICE = $20/120= 16,66$ %.

Comment: Thanks for your input but not what I was after. My fault for not expressing myself clearly enough.

Comment: Thanks for your input but not what I was after. My fault for not expressing myself clearly enough. Say I want to explain to someone how to mark up an item by 20% on SELLING price I would say "divide the cost price by the difference between 100% and 20% ie 0.8 in decimals." The result will be a selling price which, if discounted by 20%, will be equal to the original cost (and not less than cost if the item was marked up 20% of COST price or x1.2). Just wondering whether there is a mathematical term to describe the number which is the difference between x per-cent (in decimals) and 1.0